# cmake: "cannot execute binary file" on osx android build

Tags: macos, gradle, android-ndk, cmake, superpowered

On OSX, when running an android gradle build it gives me the following:

> android-sdk-macosx/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: cannot execute binary file

I've tried

- chmod +x,
- reinstalling the android sdk build tools
- googling

OSX 10.11.6 Gradle 2.14.1 Android SDK 23.0.2
Its a Superpowered(.com) Android project

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.2, it installed cmake and it now works correctly. Its unclear exactly why as it seems to be the same exact version of cmake.

Part of the problem was that I was actually using the latest stable version of IntelliJ which is still using Android Studio <2.2 level.

Comment: Hi Joel,

See http://superpowered.com/cpu-frequency-scaling-android

"The Superpowered build environment for Android is also upgraded to Gradle+CMake, which is now the new official build environment, recommended by Google. In the past 3 years we have seen 3 different environments and we hope Google finally settles with the current solution, as Android’s build system should be finally "ready"."